# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'explore', but I'm not using numbers. Only returning a list of shows. Any Ideas?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm pretty new to Django, and I'm having a hard time figuring out this error code. A lot of my searches on google lead to people using actual numbers and integers, but my **ExploreListView** is just suppose to show a list of shows stored in my database.

I followed the exact same way I did for my **ShowListView** and I am not receiving that error. I've looked over it so many times line for line, and I am not sure why ShowListView is working with no error, but ExploreListView is having the error.

How can I solve this error code?

**Please ELI5**

Traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/shows/explore/

Django Version: 1.11.4
Python Version: 3.6.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'shows']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get
  115.         self.object = self.get_object()

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get_object
  38.             queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  784.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  802.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1250.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1276.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1210.             condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_lookup
  1104.                 return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in __init__
  24.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  74.             return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  966.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /shows/explore/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'explore'
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from shows.models import Show

from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView

class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = "shows/index.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Show.objects.all()

class ShowListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'shows/index.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get("slug")
        if slug:
            pass
        else:
            queryset = Show.objects.all()
            return queryset

class ShowDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Show.objects.all()

class ExploreListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'shows/explore.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Show.objects.all()
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from shows.views import ShowListView, ShowDetailView, ExploreListView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ShowListView.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\w+)/$', ShowDetailView.as_view()),
    url(r'^explore/$', ExploreListView.as_view()),
]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Show(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    synopsis = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    premiered = models.DateField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True)
    runtime = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True)
    network = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    imdb = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    thetvdb = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    tvrage = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    next_airing = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True,blank=True)
    avg_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Season(models.Model):
    shows = models.ForeignKey(Show, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    season_number = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True,blank=True)
    season_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    season_rating = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True,blank=True)
    season_image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    season_premiered = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    season_synopsis = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.season_title

class Episode(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True,blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True,blank=True)
    aired = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**edit:**

Explore.html:

```
{% extends 'shows/base.html'%}



{% block body %}

<div class="container-fluid">


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Search Filters
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end of search -->


    {% for items in object_list %}


         <div class ="anime-card">

             <h3 class="main-title">{{ x.show }}</h3>


             <i class="material-icons" id="card-settings" >filter_list</i>
             <i class="material-icons" id="card-flag" >flag</i>

                <div class="status-marks">
                    <div class="hideme">
                        <div class="mark watching">Watching</div>
                        <div class="mark onhold">On-hold</div>
                        <div class="mark dropped">Dropped</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <ol class = "tags">
                    <li>{{ items.genre }}</li>
                 </ol>

                <div class="card-body">
                     <div class="poster"><img src="{{ items.image }}" alt="" /> </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="details-grid">
                    <ul class="anime-studios">
                        <li>{{ items.network }}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

{#              <div class="info">Creator: {{ x.creator }}</div>#}
        <div class="date">Status: {{ items.status }}</div>
        <div class="synopsis">
            <p>{{ items.synopsis }}</p>
            <p>(Source: Some Source Here)</p>
        </div>

        <ol class="related-links">
                    <li>Site</li>
                    <li>Youtube</li>
                    <li>Netflix</li>
                    <li>Hulu</li>
                    <li>IMDB</li>
                </ol>

         </div>

    {% endfor %}


</div> <!-- end of products -->

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try reordering your URLs. I don't do a lot of Django, so I'm not sure, but maybe it's matching on the wrong URL binding.

Comment: Pleas show templates

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup is templates another name for my html? I added the html code. Thanks for your time

Comment: @PhilipStark That worked! I'm a bit sad I spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to figure out this problem, only to find out I had to reorder my urls. :'(

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url matches two of Yours patterns: `^(?P<pk>\w+)/$` and `^explore/$`.

Django get first matched pattern (`^(?P<pk>\w+)/$`) and render `ShowDetailView` with `pk=explore`.

URL patterns must be set in order:

- more detailed
- most general

EDIT:

PK must be integer? Right? If yes, change Your pattern to `^(?P<pk>\d+)/$`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thanks for breaking it down for me, I appreciate it